# Wordpress Password Protected Page Execution Hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added one more field, email, to Password Protected Pages and I want to set a cookie when the user submit the form. My problem is that I don't know what hook gets executed when the form with action `wp-login.php?action=postpass` gets fired.

I looked into [this file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-login.php?rev=41782#L447) but I coudn't figure it out.

Should I add `add_action( 'login_form_postpass', 'my_function' );`

Not very clear for me how to do this. Any hint whould be awesome.

Comment: I guess that post can help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993482/wordpress-protect-page-by-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993482/wordpress-protect-page-by-login)

Comment: No at all. I want to add a new field to the password-protect form and set a cookie when the form is executed. This has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Sorry ... wrong link! Here we go: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172916/custom-form-for-password-protected-page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172916/custom-form-for-password-protected-page)

Comment: Actually I was very close. 

add_filter( 'login_form_postpass', 'postpass_custom' );

function postpass_custom() {
  // some code
}

This gets executed before the post password form. And it seems to be what I need. Thanks